# Colour pandas columns using different colourmaps per column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a data frame with three colums $A$, $B$ and $C.$ Everything is numeric, columns $A$ and $B$ increase from worse to better while columns $C$ increases from better to worse. I want to colour the cells using a gradient column-wise such that it goes from white to red in the columns $A$ and $B$ but it is reversed in the columns $C.$

> In the example below, columns `A`and `B` produce exactly what I want. Is there a way below to tell `df` to use the `background_gradient` method *reversed* for the columns `C`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B":[4,6,10], "C":[1,3,7]})
df.style.background_gradient("Reds")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just specify the cmap and chain the `background_gradient`:

```
df.style.background_gradient("Reds").background_gradient("Reds_r", subset='C')
```

Output:

[image]

In generals, if you have a mapping of column-cmap, you can do a loop:

```
# column-cmap mapping
cmaps = {'A': 'Reds', 'B':'Greens'}

# default gradient
style = df.style.background_gradient()

# loop
for col, cmap in cmaps.items():
    style = style.background_gradient(cmap, subset=col)
    
# view the result
style
```

And you get:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.